# I can't understand what is the difference between Redirect mode and Proxy mode in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am confused the differentiation between redirect mode and proxy mode in active storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

referencing: [Active Storage Overview](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#serving-files)

In all use cases of the words, the meanings of "redirect" and "proxy" have a similar meaning:

- redirect: "do it yourself"
- proxy: "okay, I'll do it for you"

if you use the "redirect" option, then the users browser will do the work of sending the file to the remote storage.

if you use the "proxy" option, then the ruby server will do the work of sending the file to the remote storage.

does that help?

Comment: I really appreciate your answer
can you explain with example?

Comment: If you can edit your question with some source code, I'll add in some examples